# Procedural geometry or bump map for stitching?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm working on an outfit on a character and am going back and forth on stitching for the fabric. I am rendering in EEVEE and will be baking for animation. I found a frame from the movie Ratatouille that shows the king of stitching I am doing. Would using geometry nodes to add stitches to the cloth then baking be the best way to go or, bump maps on images?[image]

Comment: Hello ! Unfortunately these kind of open-ended questions are off-topic on this site, because there is no objective answer. It depends on your workflow. You can use a bump map stencil texture, actual geometry, a baked map, an overlay in compositing, etc. Would you mind rephrasing your question so it is more self-contained and easier to answer canonically ? In case you don't feel like it, you can go on https://blenderartists.org/ which encourage back and forth open ended discussions. Cheers

Comment: Bump or Normal map are probably the easiest ways to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: It's NOT procedural or geonodes but in case, you can use a *Normal Map* (or height maps):

Unwrap your object, create an image that has a background of Hex:8080FF (default normal map color), plug it into the *Output* of your material. Prepare a stitch normal map image that you'll use as stencil. Switch your 3D scene to *Texture Paint*, open the *N > Tool* panel, switch your *Draw* brush to *Stencil*, select your stencil image:

[image]

Paint on the surface of your object (right click to move the stencil, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> right click to rotate, <kbd>Shift</kbd> right click to scale):

[image]

Once you're good, give your object back its material, plug the normal map you've created into a *Normal Map* node that you plug into the *Normal* input of your *Diffuse* or *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Comment: That looks like the best way to go. Thanks!